# Page issue with bioRxiv

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, overleaf, arxiv

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws) to generate a bioRxiv preprint. This includes two files merged together, the main text and supplementary information. However, when page numbering, the bottom-right of the first page shows

[image]

Showing 1-21, rather than just 1, where 21 is the last page of the supplementary info. The other pages are single-numbered. Is it possible to simply remove this feature on the first page, or change it to show only the pages on the main text?

**My attempt:** Without delving into the bioRxiv template, I was able to use `setcounter` at the end of the supplementary info as follows

```
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{17}
```

where 17 is the last page of the main text. This fixes the issue, but it generates an extra blank page. Could I somehow hide/ghost this page, yet keeping the last page number fixed?

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Miyase unfortunately I am not able to provide an MWE, but I will edit it to explain my attempted workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class file `zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv.cls` contains this definition:

```
\def\aBioRXiv{{\footnotesize
    \footerfont \@leadauthor\ifnum \value{authors} > 1\hspace{2pt}\textit{et al.}\fi\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}bio\textcolor{red}{R}$\chi$iv\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}\today\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}\thepage\textendash\pageref{LastPage}
  }}
```

Make that

```
\def\aBioRXiv{{\footnotesize
    \footerfont \@leadauthor\ifnum \value{authors} > 1\hspace{2pt}\textit{et al.}\fi\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}bio\textcolor{red}{R}$\chi$iv\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}\today\hspace{7pt}|\hspace{7pt}\thepage
  }}
```

i.e. remove `\textendash\pageref{LastPage} }}`

There is also an error message about `cleveref`. Remove the first occurrence of `\RequirePackage{cleveref}`

And, by the way, the watermark doesn't work with modern LaTeX. So take out (or comment out) this part:

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifwatermark%
  \newwatermark[allpages,color=gray!20,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}
  \fi
}
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about the `lastpage` package, quite useful. Interestingly enough, if you label the last page of the main text (`\label{maintext_finalpage}`, e.g.), you can simply reference it by changing the argument in `\pageref`, in that same code. No need for `\setcounter` shenanigans. Thank you!

Comment: This is a minor comment: for some reason, when clicking the linked page (the 17, in 1-17, e.g.), it does not directly move me to that page, but rather the page where the bibliography starts. Note that I have put the label `\label{maintext_finalpage}` after all the code in `01_Article_MainText.text`, including the bibliography. Any idea why?

Comment: Adding `\phantomsection` before `\label` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick

```
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{17+1}
\phantomsection
```

Would be nice, however, to either make it automatic (instead of manually inputting the number of the page, 17) or actually edit the bioRxiv `\documentclass`. Any suggestions are appreciated.